# WordPress defer script plugin not load website

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to speed up the loading of my wordpress website. I write a simple plugin that will add the defer attribute to some scripts that are used by the custom theme I've installed. I'm facing the issue that the site is locked to the preloader screen and no error is present in the chrome dev console nor xdebug error are showed. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I don't know, is possible that the main javascript file that is responsable to load the theme are not loaded also if isn't present in the array of the scripts that are processed to add the defer attribute? 
All the scripts are dependencies of the theme and are using jQuery that is not part of the list. 
Any help will be appreciated.

```
class WP_scriptDefer {

  private $scripts = [
    'bootstrap.min.js',
    'lazyload.min.js',
    'viewportchecker.min.js',
    'universal-parallax.min.js',
  ];

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->init();
  }

  public function init()
  {
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', [$this, 'deferScripts'], 10 );
  }

  public function deferScripts()
  {
    foreach( $this->scripts as $script ){
      if( true == strpos($tag, $script) ){
          return str_replace('src', 'defer="defer" src', $tag);
      }
    }
  }

}

new WP_scriptDefer;
```

Comment: Maybe problem in $tag

Comment: @Dmitry can you give me an explaination? I've taken the example to add the attribute from a website that is using this inside the `function.php` file and I've adapted it for the OOP of my plugin so I don't know how the tag variable will be taken from wordpress and is available inside the plugin

Comment: Add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE);` to your wp-config.php and see if there is an error.

Comment: I've tried, but no error is logged and the plugin is activated correctly. Maybe I need to load also the main js file as defer script?

Answer (score 0):

I edit your class, check it please:

```
class WP_scriptDefer
{

    private $scripts = [
            'bootstrap.min.js',
            'lazyload.min.js',
            'viewportchecker.min.js',
            'universal-parallax.min.js',
        ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }

    public function init()
    {
        add_filter('script_loader_tag', [ $this, 'deferScripts'], 10, 3);
    }

    public function deferScripts( $tag, $handle, $src  )
    {
        foreach( $this->scripts as $script ){
            if( true === strpos($tag, $script) ){
                 return str_replace('src', 'defer="defer" src', $tag);
            }
        }

        return $tag;
    }

}

new WP_scriptDefer;
```

Comment: Ok, I will test your fix suggestion. I've omitted the `$tag` `$handle` and `$src` vars as arguments for the second method of my class because I didn't know that they are required, but this is a mistake of mine because I don't work always with wordpress so I don't know how are managed the arguments of a function that is inside a class. I'll let you know.

Comment: Nothing, the `async` or `defer` attribute isn't added to the scripts. I think that also a foreach is needed to iterate over the array and replace the old tag with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

After a day and also thanks to the suggestion of Dmitry I've found the correct way to let the plugin work. The array scripts needs to contain the names assigned inside the `wp_enqueue_script()` of each script and not the file name. This isn't very clear over the web because usually this filter is applied directly inside the `function.php` of a theme. 
Here is the full working code:

```
<?php 
class WP_deferScripts {

  private $defer_scripts = [
    'bootstrap',
    'lazyload',
    'swiper',
  ];

  public function __construct()
  {
    add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', [$this, 'deferScripts'], 10, 2);
  }

  public function deferScripts( string $tag, string $handle ) : string
  {
    #var_dump($handle, $tag);
    foreach( $this->defet_scripts as $script ){
      if( $script === $handle ){
        return str_replace('src', 'defer="defer" src', $tag);
      }
    }
    return $tag;
  }

}

?>
```